# AWS Auditor Role - AWSCloudTrailFullAccess Or AWSCloudTrailReadOnlyAccess

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudtrail

For AWS Auditor role, do we need to provide AWSCloudTrailFullAccess or its enough to provide AWSCloudTrailReadOnlyAccess?

Answer (score 0):

AWS has an Amazon Managed Policy for Security Auditor named "SecurityAudit". This policy does not include most of the APIs in AWSCloudTrailReadOnlyAccess.

I recommend either using this policy as is, or basing your Auditor Role upon this policy. Document each API that you grant or deny access to that differs from this policy.

```
arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/SecurityAudit
```

Comment: "Cloudtrail" is available in "SecurityAudit". Please Check This link : https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home#policies/arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/SecurityAudit

Comment: I don't understand your comment. As I said in my answer referring to SecurityAudit: This policy does not include most of the APIs in AWSCloudTrailReadOnlyAccess. My intent is that you don't need all of the permissions that you described. Only the CloudTrail permissions in SecurityAudit policy.

Comment: Thank you for providing the details. I think i understood your explanation incorrectly in the beginning. I do understand the "AWSCloudTrailReadOnlyAccess" has more API's which are not required for audit. Since the "Access Levels" mentioned in "SecurityAudit" for "CloudTrail" are "List, Read", AWSCloudTrailReadOnlyAccess permission is enough for audior role. Please correct me if i am wrong here.

Comment: What is your goal? A Security Auditor, or someone who can access CloudTrail.

Comment: I need to create a Auditor user account and provide access to "CloudTrail". I have concern that i should not give permissions to him more then what he needs.

Comment: @pa1 you are correct. `AWSCloudTrailReadOnlyAccess` is enough for audit purposes.